# Api to count number of status,photos,friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am wondering that can we count number of photos,status updates and friends of facebook users using **php sdk** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook graph API does not provide any counter that can be read to count number of photos, status updates, friends.  It needs to be done after fetching the response data.